# Debug logs not working when deployed on IIS. It is working in development environment

Tags: c#, log4net

In Development environment, All logging is created which includes INFO and DEBUG Logs but when we deploy it on IIS , only INFO logs get created but no DEBUG logs.

I have tried by changing priority value to INFO as well as DEBUG too, currently it is ALL but no success for DEBUG logs

Please assist.

File: Web.config

```
<log4net debug="true">
<appender name="RollingFileAppenderSize" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <param name="file" value="C:\\Temp\\BSRollingFileAppenderSize.log" />
  <param name="appendToFile" value="true" />
  <param name="rollingStyle" value="Size" />
  <param name="maxSizeRollBackups" value="10" />
  <param name="maximumFileSize" value="10MB" />
  <param name="staticLogFileName" value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c [%M] - %m%n" />
  </layout>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <param name="LevelMin" value="ALL"/>
  </filter>
</appender>
<appender name="SessionsAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <param name="file" value="C:\\Temp\\BSSessions.log" />
  <param name="appendToFile" value="true" />
  <param name="rollingStyle" value="Size" />
  <param name="maxSizeRollBackups" value="10" />
  <param name="maximumFileSize" value="10MB" />
  <param name="staticLogFileName" value="true" />
  <layout type="Framework.Common.Logging.CsvPatternLayout, Framework.Common">
    <header value="DateTime,Level,Type,Action,Message&#13;&#10;" />
    <conversionPattern value="%date{M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss.fff}%newfield%level%newfield%type%newfield%property{Action}%newfield%message%endrow" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <!-- ALL, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, OFF -->
    <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppenderSize" />
</root>
<logger name="Framework.Common.Commands.Handlers.Sessions">
  <level value="INFO" />                                                                
  <appender-ref ref="SessionsAppender" />
</logger>
</log4net>
```

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET Core application? Did you check the content of the appsettings.X.json files?

Comment: This is Silverlight application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you a full configuration example so you can adapt it to your case. LevelMin to ALL

```
 <log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="folder\logfile.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <MaxSizeRollBackups value="20" />
      <MaximumFileSize value="40MB" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{HH:mm:ss:fff} [%thread] %-5level %logger{1} - %message%newline" />
      </layout>

      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">

        <param name="LevelMin" value="ALL"/>
      </filter>

      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    </appender>
    <root>

      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Comment: When i add below line and run , same thing happen only INFO logs no DEBUG logs
<filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <param name="LevelMin" value="ALL"/>
</filter>

after adding this below line my application stops working (means stop accepting my credentials to login). 
<staticLogFileName value="true" />
After removing above line , application starts working.

Thanks for assistance.

Comment: No Sir, I had tried same as you suggested above but it won't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should setup level to "DEBUG":

```
<log4net debug="true">
    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppenderSize"/>
    </root>
</log4net>
```

Comment: Did you try to setup <log4net debug="true"> ?

Comment: I tried with this <level value="DEBUG" /> but unfortunately samething happen , only INFO logs appearing not DEBUG logs.

Comment: Thanks Eugene! Tried with <log4net debug="true">  option too. earlier it was false but still same logs appearing.

Comment: At least it should print now which config file log4net ist using. Are you shure that the application uses the config you think it does?